# Gravity and graviton

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

If gravity is merely a consequence of massive bodies and the curvature of spacetime, why do we believe a graviton should exist in order to transmit gravitational forces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nature of gravity: gravitons, curvature of space-time or both?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427/nature-of-gravity-gravitons-curvature-of-space-time-or-both). See also [Is the quantization of gravity necessary for a quantum theory of gravity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52211), [Is the graviton hypothetical?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119254) and  [What are the reasons to expect that gravity should be quantized?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6980).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I'm new to stack exchange. I didn't know how to look up if this question was asked before

Comment: You're welcome, and don't worry about the duplicate. At first, it is very difficult for new users to find old questions. You'll learn with time. See you around! :-)